# Non linear systems of equations (Convergence).

Tags: nonlinear-system

I am an engineering student and I don't have any mathematical background in iterative methods. I am trying to solve a non-linear system of 14 equations and 14 unknowns as part of a project. I tried solving the system using both Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods. However, I have failed to obtain convergence in both cases. I would be grateful if someone could give some insight on how to approach such a problem.

Comment: In general there are many possibilities, but the most known option for iterative method for non-linear equations (or systems of them) si imho the Newtno's iterative method.

Comment: Any additional information about the problem might help. One might also consider the generalization fo the secant metho, e.g., BFGS or DFP methods. Another idea might be some instance of the continuation method.